# sendKeys is not sending '@' character in WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing below problem. Can anyone provide me the solution?

Problem: WebDriver sendKeys method is not sending `@` character to a text box.. 
I tried normally- i.e, `sendKeys("Test@123")`, but passing `Test123` only...

I tried below as well, but none of them worked..

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(<xpath expr>)).sendKeys("Test\@123");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(<xpath expr>)).sendKeys("Test\\@123");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(<xpath expr>)).sendKeys("Test/@123");
```

I can not provide the website URL, as it can not be accessible outside.
Just fyi, its an asp.net application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What versions are you running of all relevant details - webdriver, browser, java, etc.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am using webdriver using java.

Comment: I could tell from your tag and the language you used, I was asking what versions are you running? :)

Comment: Webdriver 2.33 [Latest version] and FF 15.0..

Comment: Mark, I am able to pass in other websites..But its not working in our website.. I can not share the website, as it can not be accessible outside..

Comment: That's an old version of Firefox. Have you tried updating it and seeing if you face the same problem? From what else you've said though I do have to ask - can you manually enter a `@` into this particular website and is it captured normally?

Comment: Can you do this manually in your application?

Comment: Hi Mark and Chetan, I tried manually and it is working..But using sendKeys(), its not working...

Comment: I tried below as well..But none of them worked.. :( 'fd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtLoginID']")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(64)));'
'fd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtLoginID']")).sendKeys(Character.toString((char)64));'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replace special characters with its codes?
For example:

```
>>> a='@'
>>> ord(a)
64
>>> string="test"+chr(64)+'123'
>>> string
'test@123'
```